# What is `Something#A` in scala

Tags: scala

I found the following syntax in Scala. I have never seen `#` and couldn't find much information about it? What does `#` mean?

```
case class WithRole(role: Role) extends Authorization[User, DefaultEnv#A]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's one of way in scala to refer a type.  I quote from Scala in Depth:

> Types within Scala are referred to via two mechanisms: the hash ( #) and dot ( .)
>   operators. The dot operator can be thought of doing the same for types as it does for
>   members of an object. It refers to a type found on a specific object instance. This is
>   known as a path-dependent type. When a method is defined using the dot operator
>   to a particular type, that type is bound to a specific instance of the object. This means
>   that you can’t use a type from a different object, of the same class, to satisfy any type
>   constraints made using the dot operator. The best way to think of this is that there’s a
>   path of specific object instances connected by the dot operator. For a variable to
>   match your type, it must follow the same object instance path. You can see an exam-
>   ple of this later.
>   The hash operator ( # ) is a looser restriction than the dot operator. It’s known as a
>   type projection, which is a means of referring to a nested type without requiring a
>   path of object instances. This means that you can reference a nested type as if it
>   weren’t nested.